# Why does Pig distribution include Zebra? Does Pig depend on Zebra?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, bigdata

Whenever you download Pig (for example from here http://www.eng.lsu.edu/mirrors/apache/pig/)
It always includes Zebra and Hadoop with it.

**Why does Pig depend on Zebra? (Does it?)**

**What is relation between Zebra and Pig?**

I'm using pig 0.7 but need to upgrade to 0.9.2+
Is it possible to use older version of Zebra with newer version of Pig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.apache.org/pig/zebra

I believe it is a very useful tool but not a required one. Zebra is mostly used a very convenient storage system on top of hadoop and pig can take advantage of zebra but I don't think it has to use it.